# How to create rounded corners like the sample?

Tags: css

consider blue section as a container like div. I want to have this with rounded corners like the sample. I used border-radius property but couldn't create the same. Also I searched a lot and couldn't fine anything like this. 
p.s. I know clip-path property is a good option for this but I want something with more support on browsers.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Use border-radius on the bottom corners;

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  border-radius: 0 0 50% 50%; /* topleft topright bottomright bottomleft */
  background: #f90;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```